# How to handle url which contains dashes in paramaters in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have defined the routes as the following.

```
Route::get('busses-from-{from}-to-other-city', 'Controller@method_a')->name('route_name_one');
Route::get('busses-from-{from}-to-other-road', 'Controller@method')->name('route_name');
```

Everything is working fine, but when I pass the **{from}** value with dashes it cause the problem. (404 not found).

As an example the link/url `abc.com/busses-from-SouthAfrica-to-other-city` works fine, but when I add the `-` in the `SouthAfrica` it cause the problem. So `abc.com/busses-from-South-Africa-to-other-city` didn't work at all.

**{from}** value can contain one or more words that's why I'm asking the solution of this here.

I know there is option to add `+` or `_` in the url but that is bad for the SEO and SEO is most important part of this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set [the constraint](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) for this parameter using `->where()` to include the dash. This way Laravel knows what this parameter will look like.

```
Route::get('busses-from-{from}-to-other-city', 'Controller@method_a')
    ->name('route_name_one')
    ->where('from', '[A-Za-z0-9-]+');
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.